# how to use one function variables to another in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, function, variables, automation

Here is my code....

```
import  openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart,Reference


    def spread_sheet(filename,sheetname):
        wb = xl.load_workbook(f'{filename}')   > i have to use these wb and sheet variables to all these functions down
        sheet= wb[f'{sheetname}']


    def total_horizontaly(row_start,row_end,col_start,col_end,Destination):
        tot=0
        for row in range(row_start,row_end+1):
            for col in range(col_start,col_end+1):
                cell =sheet.cell(row, col)
                tot += cell.value
            tot_marks =sheet.cell(row,f'{Destination}')
            tot_marks.value = tot


    def average_horizontaly(row_start,row_end,col_start,col_end,Desination):
        tot=0
        for row in range(row_start, row_end):
            for col in range(col_start, col_end):
                cell =sheet.cell(row, col)
                tot += cell.value
            avg=tot/(col_end+1-col_start)
            avg_marks=sheet.cell(row,f'{Desination}')
            avg_marks.value=avg


    def Save(filename):
        wb.save(f'{filename}')
```

> I had tried using class ,,,  it's worked but it's not satisfy my results

Comment: Unless you declare them as global variables you won't be able to use them anywhere. However you really should return them and then pass them to the functions that they are needed in.

Comment: @GSD Thank you very much.. It worked and my program did well too